# Get the highest value from a given column in a datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatable

I have a datatable that has a column "Pending Approval Number".  I need to get the highest number in that column to display to a user as the next available.  I have seen some examples of how to do this but I have not been able to get them to work.  I know i could loop each DataRow in the DataTable and check the value and store it if it is higher than the last. But I know there has to be a better way.

Here is how the DataTable is filled.

```
strSQL = "Select * from JobInvoice";
DataTable dtApprovalNumber = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter daApprovalNumber = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);
daApprovalNumber.Fill(dtApprovalNumber);
```

A change to the SQL query or code to pull it from the datatable are both welcome.

EDIT: After getting the solution for my original numeric column, I found the second column that I need to do this for is string.  The solution was also provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to get highest Value from DataTable in code not in sql, then You can just use linq like below:

```
int highestNumber = dtApprovalNumber.AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<int>("SomeIntegerColumn");
```

EDIT.

According to Your comment - if You want to calculate max value from a string column which holds numbers(don't get it why) You can go with something like that:

```
int highestNumber = dtApprovalNumber.AsEnumerable().Max(x => int.Parse(x.Field<string>("SomeStringColumn")));
```

Please Note that if any of those string values is not convertable it will fail then You will have to do it other way.

EDIT.2

Since I've just tried it I'll share with You - the situation when You have string Column and You are not sure if all of them are convertable(for example some might be empty). See below:

```
int tempVariable;
int highestNumber = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => int.TryParse(x.Field<string>("SomeColumn"), out tempVariable))
            .Max(m => int.Parse(m.Field<string>("SomeColumn")));
```

Comment: That works for the Pending Approval Number. I also have a string field with number values that I need to get the highest.  Will this work on a string field?

Comment: Please keep the original for int in your answer as well.

Comment: Here You go, read 'please note' part and if this situation is possible in Your case - let me know I'll prepare another version for You.

Comment: I know. Not sure why they are using string numeric field for one and string for another. But I don't have control over the database.

Comment: ye, I've seen it many times in different companies. It's always making me angry.

Comment: x.field<string> is saying System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'field' and no extension method 'field' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Missing namespace. Give me a second i'll check it in VS

Comment: Why calculate a max in C# when MySQL can `MAX` for you? MySQL will always do this in less time and with less code.

Comment: It's true but if You already loaded some Table(because You need the data) then it makes no sense to Query db again

Comment: @eirikir It is correct that I already populate this table to use the data. So I would have to get this high number and then get the data.  That was a possibility but getting it from the table is a better solution in this situation.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you MajkeloDev

Answer (score 2):

```
Select max(`Pending Approval Number`) from JobInvoice
```

You can do a maxvalue + 1 to show it as next available number.

Comment: Is that going to return just a column named 'Pending Approval Number' with the high value?

Comment: The question is tagged `mysql`, so `[ ]` doesn't work. Additionally this returns the literal string `'Pending Approval Number'` while mysql needs backticks instead of single quotes..

Comment: @dnoeth..thanks for pointing that out.modified it to replace `''` with ``

Comment: Thank you vkp.  I'll keep this in my SQL notes.